# How to get post data in yesod?

Tags: yesod, yesod-forms

Hello I want to manually insert a data in the table and also i used the lookupPostParam.

here's the code in Posting a New News.

```
      postNewsR :: Handler Html
      postNewsR = do
                now <- liftIO getCurrentTime
                newsTitle <- lookupPostParam "title"
                newsUrl <- lookupPostParam "news_url"
                newsSnapshot <- lookupPostParam "news_snopshot"
                newsArea <- lookupPostParam "news_area"
                newsSubject <- lookupPostParam "news_subject"
                newsContent <- lookupPostParam "news_content"

               newsId <- runDB $ insert News newsTitle newsUrl newsSnapshot newsContent False Nothing now Nothing

              redirect NewsR
```

but it gives me this Following error:

```
      Couldn't match type ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Reader.ReaderT
                   (PersistEntityBackend
                      (Data.Text.Internal.Text
                       -> Data.Text.Internal.Text
                       -> Data.Text.Internal.Text
                       -> Data.Text.Internal.Text
                       -> Bool
                       -> Maybe Int
                       -> UTCTime
                       -> Maybe UTCTime
                       -> News))
                   m0
                   (Key
                      (Data.Text.Internal.Text
                       -> Data.Text.Internal.Text
                       -> Data.Text.Internal.Text
                       -> Data.Text.Internal.Text
                       -> Bool
                       -> Maybe Int
                       -> UTCTime
                       -> Maybe UTCTime
                       -> News))’
          with ‘Maybe Data.Text.Internal.Text
                -> Maybe Data.Text.Internal.Text
                -> Maybe Data.Text.Internal.Text
                -> Maybe Data.Text.Internal.Text
                -> Bool
                -> Maybe a0
                -> UTCTime
                -> Maybe a1
                -> Control.Monad.Trans.Reader.ReaderT
                     (YesodPersistBackend App) (HandlerT App IO) t0’
         Expected type: Maybe Data.Text.Internal.Text
           -> Maybe Data.Text.Internal.Text
           -> Maybe Data.Text.Internal.Text
           -> Maybe Data.Text.Internal.Text
           -> Bool
           -> Maybe a0
           -> UTCTime
           -> Maybe a1
           -> YesodDB App t0
         Actual type: Control.Monad.Trans.Reader.ReaderT
             (PersistEntityBackend
                (Data.Text.Internal.Text
                 -> Data.Text.Internal.Text
                 -> Data.Text.Internal.Text
                 -> Data.Text.Internal.Text
                 -> Bool
                 -> Maybe Int
                 -> UTCTime
                 -> Maybe UTCTime
                 -> News))
             m0
             (Key
                (Data.Text.Internal.Text
                 -> Data.Text.Internal.Text
                 -> Data.Text.Internal.Text
                 -> Data.Text.Internal.Text
                 -> Bool
                 -> Maybe Int
                 -> UTCTime
                 -> Maybe UTCTime
                 -> News))
      The function insert is applied to 9 arguments,
      but its type ‘(Data.Text.Internal.Text
           -> Data.Text.Internal.Text
           -> Data.Text.Internal.Text
           -> Data.Text.Internal.Text
           -> Bool
           -> Maybe Int
           -> UTCTime
           -> Maybe UTCTime
           -> News)
          -> Control.Monad.Trans.Reader.ReaderT
               (PersistEntityBackend
                  (Data.Text.Internal.Text
                   -> Data.Text.Internal.Text
                   -> Data.Text.Internal.Text
                   -> Data.Text.Internal.Text
                   -> Bool
                   -> Maybe Int
                   -> UTCTime
                   -> Maybe UTCTime
                   -> News))
               m0
               (Key
                  (Data.Text.Internal.Text
                   -> Data.Text.Internal.Text
                   -> Data.Text.Internal.Text
                   -> Data.Text.Internal.Text
                   -> Bool
                   -> Maybe Int
                   -> UTCTime
                   -> Maybe UTCTime
                   -> News))’
```

I hope you help me, Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

---

I change something in my code. here's the update.
From lookupPostParam to runInputPost

```
    newsTitle <- runInputPost $ ireq textField "title"
    newsUrl <- runInputPost $ ireq textField "news_url"
    newsSnapshot <- runInputPost $ ireq textField "news_snopshot"
    newsArea <- runInputPost $ ireq textField "news_snopshot"
    newsSubject <- runInputPost $ ireq textField "news_snopshot"
    newsContent <- runInputPost $ ireq textareaField "news_content"

    -- Inserting it to the table News
    newsId <- insert $ News newsTitle newsUrl newsSnapshot newsContent False Nothing now Nothing
```

Now it gives me 2 error:

```
 1. Couldn't match type ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Reader.ReaderT
                   SqlBackend m0’
          with ‘HandlerT App IO’
    Expected type: HandlerT App IO (Key News)
    Actual type: Control.Monad.Trans.Reader.ReaderT
             SqlBackend m0 (Key News) …
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful to see how you've defined your `News` entity...

Let's take a look at the signature of the function in question:

```
lookupPostParam :: (MonadResource m, MonadHandler m)
                => Text
                -> m (Maybe Text)
```

That says `lookupPostParam` takes a `Text` argument, returns a `Maybe Text`, and lives in the `m` monad. When you invoke `lookupPostParam`, the `<-` keyword unwraps the `m` monad for us. So `newsTitle` in

```
newsTitle <- lookupPostParam "title"
```

has the type `Maybe Text`. I would imagine your `News` defines its fields as `Text` types, so you still have to handle the `Maybe` before you will have values you can insert in your database. E.g.,

```
case newsTitle of
 Nothing -> redirect NewsR -- and handle the error, return 400 perhaps
 Just title -> do
   newsUrl <- lookupPostParam "news_url"
   case newsUrl of
    Nothing -> redirect NewsR -- and handle the error
    Just url -> do
      -- and so on
```

Once you've unwrapped `Maybe` from the return values of `lookupPostParam`, you should have no trouble applying them to `insert`.

```
newsId <- runDB $ insert $ 
          News title url snapshot content False Nothing now Nothing
```

Take a look at [Data.Maybe](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html) or reply back here if you're still stuck.

Comment: Can you select my answer so the question closes?